# Some space characters are not entered in KDE5 apps

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, kubuntu

In Kubuntu 16.04, switch to Arabic keyboard layout, the press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> both in `kate` and `gedit`. In `kate` nothing is entered  while there is no problem in gedit. How can this problem be solved? There is similar problem with some other Unicode characters and other KDE apps and even in KDE environment text boxes.

There was no such problem in Kubuntu 14.04 with KDE4 Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this issue after a fresh boot?  I have a similar problem after waking up from sleep.  See [Certain keys not working correctly after resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805398/certain-keys-not-working-correctly-after-resuming-from-suspend)

Comment: The problem is not solved by a reboot. My problem seems to be a bug in Qt5 apps. The same apps compiled with Qt4 work correctly.